# Git error remote origin already exists: trying to make initial commit

Tags: git

I'm trying to push my first commit to a new Github repository and am running to issues with the remote origin. When I try to commit and push the README.txt file, everything is fine until I get to the instructions which indicate that I need to run in Command Line:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/afreymiller/personal_website.git
```

I get

```
"fatal: remote origin already exists."
```

Fair enough, I then do

```
git push -u origin master
```

as the instructions indicate, and receive the error

```
fatal: 'git@github.com/afreymiller/personal_website.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to change your repo url from SSH to HTTPS. You already have a remote origin url, so instead of adding a new one, change the existing one using the following command:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/afreymiller/personal_website.git
```

After you execute this command, your Git install will be interacting with GitHub using HTTPS, which is probably what you want. By using HTTPS instead of SSH, it will prompt you for your password every time you push to GitHub, but it is less complicated than setting up the public/private key pair that SSH requires.

Details on switching remote urls: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset your origin, do [this](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/)

From the link:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .git file from your local repository, re-initialize using `git init` to see if that fixes the issue. Its done something like that for me before - deleting .git file and starting over with `git init` fixed it for me.